# how to trim few words in 2nd column to display in a text file

Tags: sed, awk

Original:

```
'abc','X:1234','cde', 'YYY', 'XYZ'
'abc','X:2345'','cde', 'YYY', 'XYZ'
```

Want to outcome with the below, in which 2nd column trim to 4 characters, before is 6 charaters.

```
'abc','X:12','cde', 'YYY', 'XYZ'
'abc','X:23'','cde', 'YYY', 'XYZ'
```

I have only know how to get 2nd column with trim character, but don't know how to display all

```
awk -F, -vOFS="," '{print substr($2,2,4)}' test.txt  > test2.txt
result:
X:12
X:23
```

Please kindly advise with trim character and display all columns at the same time.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
awk -F, '{$2=q substr($2,2,4) q;}1' OFS=, q="'" test.txt
```

`$2=q substr($2,2,4) q` - 2nd column is modified wherein we extract 4 characters and surround it with a quote(q)

`1` - print every line

`OFS=,` Use comma as Output field separator

Comment: Thanks for that, and it now works!! Thank you so much!

Comment: @sing Since this answer works for you, please check the mark on the left of the answer to mark it as the solution.